# How can I easily see the output from a Template Haskell statement?

Tags: haskell, metaprogramming, ghc, template-haskell

I have the following Template Haskell code in my module, which is part of a larger application.

```
$(derive makeFoldable ''JStatement)
```

I suspect that the generated instance of Foldable is not exactly what I originally had in mind, but I can't find a way to verify this.  So, preferrably using only `ghci`, is it possible to view the generated instance?

I tried the following and got a syntax error and I'm guessing this is because I'm Doing It Wrong™.

```
> derive makeFoldable ''JStatement

<interactive>:1:21:
    lexical error in string/character literal at character '\''
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured it out.  If you pass `-ddump-splices` it will print the generated instances to the terminal when compiling the module.

Answer (score 3):

GHCi reports "`lexical error...`"
because you don't have Template Haskell
activated in your GHCi session.
You can activate it either
    by passing `-XTemplateHaskell` on the command line
    or from within GHCi itself:

```
ghci> :set -XTemplateHaskell
```

After fixing that, you should get an error in the likes of:

```
No instance for (Show DecsQ) arising from a use of ‘print’
In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Now,
you have several options
to print things that are inside the `Q` monad:

- Use `-ddump-splices`
  (as already pointed out in [Deniz Dogan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/765943))
- Pretty print the generated Haskell code from GHCi itself:

  ```
  > putStrLn $(stringE . pprint =<< derive makeFoldable ''JStatement)
  instance Foldable (JStatement ...)
    where foldr ... = ...
  ```
- Show the actual structure based on constructors:

  ```
  > putStrLn $(stringE . show =<< derive makeFoldable ''JStatement)
  [InstanceD [] (AppT (ConT Foldable) (... JStatement ...)) [...]]
  ```

The last two might be simplified using `runQ`,
but this does not work for code generation that
uses some Template Haskell functions,
such as `reify` operations.
This includes some (or maybe most?) derivations of the derive package.

Comment: Your answer tipped me off to the fact that you can do `:set -XTemplateHaskell` and then `:set -ddump-splices` within a ghci session. I had no idea.